# How can I select all ids with the pattern lastname.firstname

Tags: mysql

I am looking to select ids that are backwards from some standards we have outlined.

What I would like to do is this:

```
SELECT iid FROM login WHERE iid LIKE lastname'.%'
```

In theory this should catch everyone where there id is lastname.firstname instead of firstname.lastname. Either way any suggestions would be awesome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `SELECT iid FROM login WHERE iid != CONCAT(firstname,'.',lastname)`
:)

Or `SELECT iid FROM login WHERE iid LIKE CONCAT(lastname,'.%')`

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you, just couldn't wrap my head around it for some reason yesterday.